# Fibonacci calculator

Tags: rust, fibonacci-sequence

I'm trying to learn Rust and for this reason I'm reading the Rust Book. It [contains the following exercise](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch03-05-control-flow.html#summary):

> Generate the *n*th Fibonacci number.

Here's my take. Note I'm only using material from chapters 1-3 of this book (since I've only read so far yet), with the exception of `format!` which I learned by Googling it and `unreachable!`, which I learned by asking other people. I think I needed both facilities to complete the task.

```rust
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let n = loop {
        println!("Enter n to get Fₙ:");
        let mut n = String::new();
        io::stdin()
            .read_line(&mut n)
            .expect("Failed to read line");
        break match n.trim().parse() {
            Ok(n) => n,
            Err(_) => continue,
        }
    };
    
    let subscript_n = subscript(n);
    let res = fib(n);
    println!("F{subscript_n} = {res}");
}

fn fib(n: u32) -> u64 {
    match n {
        0 => 0,
        n => {
            let mut fib_i = 1u64;
            let mut fib_i_minus_1 = 0u64;
            for _ in 1..n {
                (fib_i, fib_i_minus_1) = (fib_i.checked_add(fib_i_minus_1).expect("Result too large"), fib_i);
            }
            fib_i
        }
    }
}

fn subscript(n: u32) -> String {
    match n {
        0 => format!("0"),
        mut n => {
            let mut res = String::new();
            while n != 0 {
                let digit = match n % 10 {
                    0 => '₀',
                    1 => '₁',
                    2 => '₂',
                    3 => '₃',
                    4 => '₄',
                    5 => '₅',
                    6 => '₆',
                    7 => '₇',
                    8 => '₈',
                    9 => '₉',
                    10.. => unreachable!(),
                };
                n /= 10;
                res = format!("{res}{digit}");
            }
            res
        }
    }
}
```

Comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I would create the input string outside the loop and `clear()` it before each iteration, as this is more performant (no need to allocate twice). This code isn't performance sensitive, but still a good habit.
2. `break match` is strange. I would rather use:

```rust
match n.trim().parse() {
    Ok(n) => break n,
    Err(_) => continue,
}
```

3. I would rewrite `subscript()` as follows. This is subjective but I find it more readable (although perhaps less performant):

```rust
fn subscript(n: u32) -> String {
    n.to_string()
        .chars()
        .map(|c| match c {
            '0' => '₀',
            '1' => '₁',
            '2' => '₂',
            '3' => '₃',
            '4' => '₄',
            '5' => '₅',
            '6' => '₆',
            '7' => '₇',
            '8' => '₈',
            '9' => '₉',
            _ => unreachable!(),
        })
        .collect()
}
```

If you insist on using the old version, then `format!("0")` is rather unusual way to convert a string literal to a `String` - the commonly used ways are `String::from("0")`, `"0".into()` (where the compiler can infer the target type is `String`), `"0".to_string()` and `"0".to_owned()`. I personally prefer `to_owned()` as I think it reflects the intent the best - you want to go from a borrowed `&str` to an owned `String`. For pushing a char into a `String` we got  [`String::push()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/string/struct.String.html#method.push) - `format!("{res}{digit}")` is both unidiomatic and inefficient (as it creates a copy and use the formatting machinery which is pretty heavy). You can also use string literals (`"₀"`, `"₁"`) instead of `char`s then use [`push_str()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/string/struct.String.html#method.push_str) - this may be a little more efficient as it doesn't need to determine the character length.

4. Your `subscript()` function prints the subscript backwards (my version does it correctly) - you can fix that by changing `format!("{res}{digit}")` to `format!("{digit}{res}")` or [`insert(0, digit)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/string/struct.String.html#method.insert) instead of `push()`.

The code after all changes:

````rust
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let n = {
        let mut n = String::new();
        loop {
            n.clear();
            println!("Enter n to get Fₙ:");
            io::stdin().read_line(&mut n).expect("Failed to read line");
            match n.trim().parse() {
                Ok(n) => break n,
                Err(_) => continue,
            }
        }
    };

    let subscript_n = subscript(n);
    let res = fib(n);
    println!("F{subscript_n} = {res}");
}

fn fib(n: u32) -> u64 {
    match n {
        0 => 0,
        n => {
            let mut fib_i = 1u64;
            let mut fib_i_minus_1 = 0u64;
            for _ in 1..n {
                (fib_i, fib_i_minus_1) = (
                    fib_i.checked_add(fib_i_minus_1).expect("Result too large"),
                    fib_i,
                );
            }
            fib_i
        }
    }
}

fn subscript(n: u32) -> String {
    n.to_string()
        .chars()
        .map(|c| match c {
            '0' => '₀',
            '1' => '₁',
            '2' => '₂',
            '3' => '₃',
            '4' => '₄',
            '5' => '₅',
            '6' => '₆',
            '7' => '₇',
            '8' => '₈',
            '9' => '₉',
            _ => unreachable!(),
        })
        .collect()
}
```
````

Comment: No idea how could I miss this bug about characters being printed in the wrong order :)